# Upgrade Mac OS 10.5.8 to Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, upgrade

I have a Macbook which is approx. 4 yrs old and I am now running `OS 10.5.8`.  How can I upgrade to Snow Leopard?  I need to to run Quickbooks 11.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Lion hasn't shipped yet, so Snow Leopard is your only option.

1. Ensure you meet the [minimum system requirements](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html).
2. Buy the [$30 install DVD](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MAC_OS_X_SNGL).
3. Insert DVD and follow the onscreen instructions to upgrade.